# Labview while loop not operating correctly?

Tags: loops, graphics, while-loop, labview

Im trying to make a labview program that is supposed to flip a dice and activate a specific led in order of which number it lands on, but if it lands on a 6 its supposed to make all leds blink twice. Right now if it lands on a 6 it only blinks once.

Heres the while loop i made
[image: while loop]

[image: loop 1]

if false its like this:
[image: false]

Here's how the full program looks like if anyone would like to know:
[image: full]

Answer (score 3):

You are not updating any LEDs inside your loop.

---

Your code does this if you roll a 6:

1. The while loop runs 3 times, as fast possible
2. The while loop passes the last value (*TRUE*) out.
3. This "TRUE" value enters the "OR" nodes.
4. The output of the "OR" nodes get written to the LEDs.

This means: Your LEDs only get updated *after* your while loop has stopped running.

---

If you want your LEDs to blink multiple times, you need to update them inside the while loop.

Make sure you understand the concept of [Dataflow](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361N-01/lvconcepts/block_diagram_data_flow/) and make sure your code doesn't have any Race Conditions. (If you don't understand these terms, I recommend you take a course or read a book for LabVIEW beginners)

Comment: Could you elaborate on how im supposed to accomplish this

Comment: Could you elaborate what you've tried after reading the answer, and's unclear about the current descriptions?

Comment: Im unsure on how to update while in the loop, am i supposed to put the leds inside the loop?

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: Yes, you need to put the LEDs inside the loop. You can either put the LEDs' _Terminals_ inside the loop, or you can put the LEDs' _Local Variables_ inside the loop. You will also need to add a Wait node in the loop to make it blink slowly. May I ask if you are currently taking any LabVIEW classes?

Comment: yes and we had to make 6 assignments and this was the last one.

Comment: Check your class notes for info on how to update _Indicators_ inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to JKSH's answer above, note that you'll need to have some timing involved.

As JKSH pointed out, you didn't update the LED inside the loop, but even if you had, without some delay between the updates, you probably wouldn't be able to see the blink because it would happen too quickly.

I mention this because it's possible that you'll get the updating inside the loop correct, but you won't know because it will flash too quickly for you to see.